# My .swf file does not work after protection (using software)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I used three differet software to protect my .swf files.

After protecting my files dont work anymore, (a few of them worked).

I asked support team what is wrong with their software, they said .swf files with preloader cannot be protected (sometimes).

I always have my preloader graphics and code on frame 1, all other code I put in classes.
While I work in Flash, if I get error I can see my preloader graphics blinking.

Actually thats what I see when I run 'protected file', blinking graphics.

Ofcourse Im trying to protect files without errors, they work very well before protecting.

Do you know anything about this? Why it looks like I have errors when run protected file?

How you protect files?

Answer (score 0):

Problems after file obfuscation may be caused by using too tight settings in the programs you're using, assuming that you have settings. We're using SWF Encrypt (http://www.amayeta.com/software/swfencrypt/) where you can choose many settings depending on your needs - and we don't have any problems using preloaded files.

And as for securing files. Obfuscation is good first step, making it harder for someone to read your code, but after all with tools like CheatEngine it's possible to modify running swf file. Try few tricks to make cheating as hard as possible for anyone trying it. For instance (if it's a game):

1. Store timestamps when game/round starts and ends - that way if it's timer based game, you can check if someone was slowing down or speeding up framerate.
2. Send all player scores/moves to the server and let it calculate the score again - so you can catch all the people that does data manipulation without them figuring out what happens
3. Check if your swf is running in the browser - you can do that by checking Flash Player type - and if it's run locally just stop your movie - or crash it ;)
4. Use Base64 encoding for outgoing requests or some sort of simple encryption - it might discourage people who try to sniff using firebug or Charles or whatever tool is popular these days.
5. Keep vital data in Vector instead of Array (assuming you're using AS3) - CheatEngine has trouble accessing it.

I hope this helps a bit.